# Is there an open source cross-platform push server?

Tags: php, python, comet, push, server-push

I'm currently in need of a (preferably open-source) free push server, that supports both linux and windows. I need something similar to the [Ajax Push Engine](http://www.ape-project.org/), but that project unfortunatelly does not work on windows (I could use a virtual machine, but that's not what I'm looking for).

I need to be able to push information to/from a python daemon, from a php script, to/from javascript and to a Blackberry application (built with java).

Is there any tool that could help me with that?

I've also looked into the Orbited project but frankly it lacks a lot of documentation and it's been very complicated to understand it. I'm not sure if it could work for me since it isn't actually a push server, but rather a proxy for it's built in MorbidQ server (or am I wrong?).

Would a technology like Advanced Message Queing Protocol work for a project like this? Something like RabbitMQ or ActiveMQ?

Thank you very much for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like ActiveMQ very much, especially together with Camel.

For push web technology, [cometd](http://cometd.org/) comes first to mind.

Comment: Is cometd compatible with php and python?

Comment: Python yes, not sure about PHP.